# File to Array to JTable (Index out of Bounds)

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file-io, indexoutofboundsexception

**Brief description**

I am currently writing a massive (For my skill level) java program with my first UI. My goal is to make the program use the UI to save career information to a text file and allow it to read that file into a JTable, these two actions are done through JButtons.

*The file uses a # between variables and is in the format:*

```
name#placeOfWork#description#highestSalary#lowestSalary#indexOfDegree#indexOfDegreeLevel and studYears#yearOfMatriculation#
```

The issue arose when I tried to instantiate a Career constructor (Code below) from the file by splitting the line into the necessary parts, I have no idea how this is giving me an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception as it seems to be within the array's boundaries...

---

**The Career's parameterised constructor: (Career)**

```
public final int[] ARR_STUDY_YEARS = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 10 };
public final String ARR_DEGREE[] = { "None", "Commerce", "Science", "Arts", "Computer Sciences", "Education",
        "Medicine", "Engineering" },
        ARR_DEGREE_LEVEL[] = { "None", "Matriculent", "Undergraduate", "Associate", "Bachelor", "Masters",
                "Doctorate" };

// Variables
private String name, setting, description, degree, degreeLevel, qualification;;
private int highestSalary, lowestSalary, avgSalary, sYears, matricYear;

public Career(String name, String setting, String description, int highestSalary, int lowestSalary,
        int degreeNo, int degreeLevelNo, int matricYear){
    this.name = name;
    this.setting = setting;
    this.description = description;
    this.highestSalary = highestSalary;
    this.lowestSalary = lowestSalary;
    sYears = ARR_STUDY_YEARS[degreeLevelNo];
    degreeLevel = ARR_DEGREE_LEVEL[degreeLevelNo];
    degree = ARR_DEGREE[degreeNo];
    this.matricYear = matricYear;
}
```

---

**The Code giving me an error: (CareerUI)**

```
JButton btnDisplay = new JButton("Display");

    btnDisplay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ArrayList<Career> careerList = new ArrayList<Career>();

            File file = new File("Careers.txt");

            try {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    String[] line = reader.nextLine().split("#");
                    Career career = new Career(line[0], line[1], line[2], Integer.parseInt(line[3]), Integer.parseInt(line[4]),
                            Integer.parseInt(line[5]), Integer.parseInt(line[6]), Integer.parseInt(line[7])); 
                //^ This constructor is on line 200

                    careerList.add(career);
                }
                reader.close();
                String[][] cMatrix = new String[careerList.size()][6];
                String[] header = { "Name", "Setting", "Description", "Average Salary", "Tertiary Qual. Required",
                        "Qualification" };
                for (int i = 0; i < cMatrix.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                        Career c = careerList.get(j);
                        cMatrix[i] = c.toTableSummary();
                    }
                }
                JTable table = new JTable(cMatrix, header);
                // table.set
                table.setBounds(519, 53, 489, 437);
                panel.add(table);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("There was an error while reading your file");
            }

        }
    });
```

---

**The File: (Careers.txt)**

```
Chartered Accountant#Office#Balances finances#100000#80000#1#4#2017#
Plumber#House Calls#Fixes Plumbing#50000#10000#0#0#2019#
Doctor#Clinic#Treats illness#150000#50000#6#6#2016#
Architect#Construction Firm#Designs Buildings#80000#50000#6#5#2018#
```

---

**The Error:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at career.CareerUI$3.actionPerformed(CareerUI.java:200)
```

**Update**

Just did a test with converting a text file into a multi dimensional array and it worked, the code is below. I might be close to figuring this out.

```
public class ScanToArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        int x = 0;
        String[][] multi = new String[5][5];
        while (scFile.hasNextLine()){
            String[] next = scFile.nextLine().split("#");
            multi[x][0] = next[0];
            multi[x][1] = next[1];
            multi[x][2] = next[2];
            multi[x][3] = next[3];
            multi[x][4] = next[4];
            x++;
        }
        scFile.close();
        int ln = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < multi.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < multi[i].length; j++) {
                if(i>ln){
                    System.out.println();
                    ln = i;
                }
                System.out.print("|" +multi[i][j] +"|");
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: File not found");
    }
}
}
```

The File used (test.txt)

```
0.0#0.1#0.2#0.3#0.4
1.0#1.1#1.2#1.3#1.4
2.0#2.1#2.2#2.3#2.4
3.0#3.1#3.2#3.3#3.4
4.0#4.1#4.2#4.4#4.4
```

The output:

```
|0.0||0.1||0.2||0.3||0.4|
|1.0||1.1||1.2||1.3||1.4|
|2.0||2.1||2.2||2.3||2.4|
|3.0||3.1||3.2||3.3||3.4|
|4.0||4.1||4.2||4.4||4.4|
```

Going to mess around and see if I can convert that to a Jtable and then try to work out where I went wrong initially.

Note: I am not asking what a arrayindexoutofbounds is, I am asking why this particular code is giving me it.

Comment: So you never ever checked which line of your text file causes this exception? Why?

Comment: @Tom The first line that my program attempts to convert gives the error

Comment: Then your issue is not reproducable with the information you've given use. Try to build a [mcve]. And if the first line causes the exception, then print what your code actually reads, since this is not what you've showed us here (your text file example is fine).

Comment: @Tom Thanks for that information, I am trying some stuff now, I think I might be on to something...

Answer (score 3):

There are few problems with your code:

(1) In the 4th line of your input, there is 7th index (if you split with #), which breaks when you try to get `line[7]`, which will throw  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**Buildings#80000#50000#6#5#2017#**

(2) You will not be able to parse the 6th element using `Integer.parseInt(line[6])` as it throws `NumberFormatException`

(3) The input data is not right even in the 3rd line, it has more than 7 indexes after split, which does not throw any exceptions (as you are retrieving upto 7 indexes), but ensure that correct data is passed as input.

Answer (score 0):

```
sYears = ARR_STUDY_YEARS[degreeLevelNo];
degreeLevel = ARR_DEGREE_LEVEL[degreeLevelNo];
```

You most likely don't want to use the same variable as index to different arrays.

Comment: The reason I did that is so that certain levels of study (e.g. Doctorate) use a certain number of study years (e.g 10 years)